# Android M Request Multiple permission at a single time

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, user-permissions

Hi i am updating my application [jaffna Temples](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=baman.lankahomes.lk.jaffnatemples&hl=en) . so that it can support Android M devices (v 6.0 and above).

Is there a way i can request multiple permission at a single time.
eg: I want to get the permission to read phone state and location information at the  same time.

Using this ways i can request permission one by one. But i want to rest both permission at once at the start of the application.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        } else {
            setPhoneDetails();
        }
    }
```

Please give me some suggestions. Tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way i can request multiple permission at a single time

Put more than one permission in the `String[]` that you are passing to `requestPermissions()`.

For example, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/tutorial/finish/RuntimePermTutorial), I define collections of permissions statically, such as:

```
  private static final String[] PERMS_TAKE_PICTURE={
    CAMERA,
    WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  };
```

so that I can request those permissions later:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMS_TAKE_PICTURE,
    RESULT_PERMS_INITIAL);
```