# How do I request multiple permissions at once in react native

Tags: permissions, react-native, react-native-ios

I'd like to request permissions on one page instead of waiting for each particular situation.  However, I do not want multiple popups.  Is there a way to ask for permissions with a single popup/modal.

On the android side I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385161/android-m-request-multiple-permission-at-a-single-time), which look promising, but I have yet to find something for iOS.

Comment: Hello VK1 I know it is very late. but please accept my answer if you find this helpful for someone who is looking for the same issue as i have also faced this issue.

Answer (score 22):

**In Android**

First add permissions in to the AndroidManifest.xml file and then

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
      [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA, 
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]
      ).then((result) => {
        if (result['android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION']
        && result['android.permission.CAMERA']
        && result['android.permission.READ_CONTACTS']
        && result['android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION']
        && result['android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE']
        && result['android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'] === 'granted') {
          this.setState({
            permissionsGranted: true
          });
        } else if (result['android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION']
        || result['android.permission.CAMERA']
        || result['android.permission.READ_CONTACTS']
        || result['android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION']
        || result['android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE']
        || result['android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'] === 'never_ask_again') {
          this.refs.toast.show('Please Go into Settings -> Applications -> APP_NAME -> Permissions and Allow permissions to continue');
        }
      });
  }
```

**In iOS**
In the info section of your project on XCode

- Add the permissions and the description
  say - ex: Privacy - Contacts Usage Description
  then,

  ```
  Permissions.request('photo').then(response => {
    if (response === 'authorized') {
      iPhotoPermission = true;
    }
   Permissions.request('contact').then(response => {
    if (response === 'authorized') {
      iPhotoPermission = true;
    }
  });
  });
  ```

Comment: Instead of using all of the && and || statements, you can use `Object.keys(results).every((result) => result === 'granted')` and `Object.keys(results).some((result) => result === 'never_ask_again')`

Comment: Just passing by ... the correct use of Object.keys would be : `Object.keys(results).every((key) => results[key] === 'granted')`

Comment: In both the if() conditions above, need to check === 'granted' condition for every result['item'], since their string values are evaluated as truthy.

Answer (score 7):

Makes sure you also add respective permissions in manifest file as well.

```
export async function GetAllPermissions() {
  try {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      const userResponse = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CALL_PHONE
      ]);
      return userResponse;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    Warning(err);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there anything similar for iOS?

Comment: As far as i remember putting the desired permissions in `info.plist` should work i am not sure here. if adding new react native packages is not a issue for you then i will recommend you [this](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions) else please give me some time to check how i did it and will update you.

Answer (score 2):

To request multiple permissions I will suggest you to use [npm module](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions) as its saves time and easy to setup and most important you don't have to worry about the platforms :)

**Installation**

```
npm install --save react-native-permissions
```

**Usage**

```
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions'

// Check the status of multiple permissions
  _checkCameraAndPhotos = () => {
    Permissions.checkMultiple(['camera', 'photo']).then(response => {
      //response is an object mapping type to permission
      this.setState({
        cameraPermission: response.camera,
        photoPermission: response.photo,
      })
    })
  }
```

Don't forget to add permissions to ***AndroidManifest.xml*** for android and ***Info.plist*** for iOS (Xcode >= 8).

Answer (score 0):

First add your permissions to "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" file. You can use npm module in order to achieve your goal.

```
npm install --save react-native-permissions
```

After installation, you can use *checkMultiple* function to ask multiple permissions. Following code illustrates how to ask permission for **ANDROID.CAMERA** and **ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** :

```
 checkMultiple([
  PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA,
  PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
]).then(result => {
  
  console.log(result);
  
});
```

The result will be an object like this

```
{"android.permission.CAMERA": "denied", "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE": "denied"}
```

To handle this result, you can use this basic code example

```
checkPermissions = () => {
if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
  return;
}

checkMultiple([
  PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA,
  PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
]).then(result => {
  if (
    !result ||
    !result[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA] ||
    !result[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]
  ) {
    console.log('could not get any result. Please try later.');
  }

  if (
    result[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA] === RESULTS.GRANTED &&
    result[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] === RESULTS.GRANTED
  ) {
    console.log('granted for both permissions');
    // do smthing here
  }
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to request multiple permissions at once using react-native-permissions package.

you can also implement your own conditions according to need, i am just writing a simple solution

**requestMultiple** will not ask again if permissions are already granted.

```
import { checkMultiple, requestMultiple, PERMISSIONS } from 'react-native-permissions';

const verifyPermissions = async () => {
        let perm = [ PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA, PERMISSIONS.IOS.PHOTO_LIBRARY ];
        if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
            perm = [ PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA, PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ];
        }
        let permissionStatuses = await requestMultiple(perm);
        console.log('obj', permissionStatuses);
        console.log('Camera', permissionStatuses[perm[0]]);
        console.log('photo', permissionStatuses[[ perm[1] ]]);
        const result = permissionStatuses[perm[0]];
        if (result !== 'granted') {
            Alert.alert('Insufficient permissions!', 'You need to grant camera and library access permissions to use this app.', [
                { text: 'Okay' }
            ]);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```